# Is there a way to show progress of auth triggered firebase cloud function?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am building a Next.JS app with a Firebase Backend. When a user registers, I use an auth trigger to run a function that creates a Firestore document and sets some data to it. The cloud function takes some time to complete. I would like to show the user loading screen while this cloud function runs and
This is my create user function:

```
// **1** CREATE USER 
const createUser = (email, password) => {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
};
```

I update the document as such

```
// **5** FUNCTION TO RUN WHEN A NEW USER IS CREATED
exports.newCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    const uid = user.uid;
    const userData = {
       //...someDataSource
    };

    // UPDATE CUSTOMER DOCUMENT
    return setCustomer(counting, uid) //Firestore updater function

});
// **5**
```

How can I achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot except by using a separate service to push data to your user. The `onCreate()` function is a background function that runs asynchronously and is entirely decoupled from your frontend. Anything you would want to present to your user would need to be done through custom code that you write that pushes data through some service that the app is connected to, for example Firestore.

I'm not sure about the feasibility of this because your issue seems to be that even Firestore document writes are taking too long, but let's assume that you're doing a lot of complex work with those documents that genuinely takes a long time to complete and the issue that you have with speed is not related to Firestore latency but rather from some other process's latency.

If that's the case then an example of this would be:

1. The client creates a listener to a Firestore collection that does not require authentication
2. The function fires
3. It creates a new document in that Firestore collection containing data about the progress of the function
4. The client listener receives the document creation and the UI can be updated to show that it has started
5. As the function continues it updates the document to show the progress
6. The client listener receives the document update and the UI can be updated to show that it has progressed
7. Repeat 5-6

There are limits to this approach because Firestore has limitations on [updates to a single document](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#updates_to_a_single_document). Alternatives might be Firebase Realtime DB or other similar services.